# Orientation of wire in linear position wire sensors

Tags: measurements, sensors, instrumentation

Talking about a wire potentiometer, I was wondering about the way it could be used after installation. as you know, wire sensors have a roll of wire inside them that come out of a hole, and it sounds like that the wire should always remain direct and in the same orientation as it comes out.

for example in [this link](https://www.gefran.com/it/it/download/4625/attachment/en)

you can see that the wire is always held along one axis , let's say X axis to verify the length of the wire:

[image]

if my interest is the length change ( not the absolute current value) of the wire, and the wire does move not only in X direction, but let's say also in Y (and or) Z direction , while my interest is in $\delta L$ of the wire, not only in one certain axis, how much error would we introduce to the measurement ? is there a way to approximate that ?

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are interested only in the X-component of the length change ($\delta L_X$), or are you interested in the total length change ($\delta L$)?

Comment: I edited the question : my interest is in deltaL of the wire, not only in one certain axis

Comment: Then - as far as I can see- I think your error in measuring $\delta L$ should be zero. I mean apart from friction, that might hinder the movement a bit, I don't think that you should get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see- I think your error in measuring $\delta L$ should be zero.

I mean apart from the increased friction, that might hinder the movement a bit, I don't think that you should get any error in the measurement of length.

Comment: did you down vote my question?

Comment: no I didn't. some one else did.

Comment: if you believe it was a good question , could you assign your vote please?

Comment: I would appreciate that